# Ways to refers to two people who were about to marry or just married

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests

I wrote the following:

> A bright red carpet ran all the way from the entrance to right beneath
>   the altar. Enclosing it on both sides, were two rows of long
>   benches—each of them with a tiny ribbon shaped as a wedding dress.
>   Together they looked like a gathering of ancient souls; spirits who
>   had come from the past to congratulate the **newly committed lovers.**
>
> ---
>
> “And now you may kiss the bride,” the priest finally said. The groom
>   nodded, and then turned to look at his **new wife**.

Are **newly committed lovers** and **new wife** good enough for those passages? Or is there a better way to refer to the bride and the groom? (I don't want to use *couple* because I already used it too many times).

Comment: Isn't this a proper *phrase-request*?

Comment: I think the question has been put on hold because you are asking the community to proofread your excerpt and express an opinion on two expressions which are perfectly acceptable in the English language. You need to edit your question and express your doubt about the use of these terms. Something along the lines of, is "newly" an appropriate adverb to use with "committed lovers" Is it more appropriate to say, "freshly" instead? It's just a suggestion, don't take it up! "New wife" could have different interpretations...

Comment: His "newly wedded wife" I think would be better and "newly-weds". But, you see, that's an opinion.

Comment: "were about to marry" implies that they *didn't in fact marry*. When I first read your Q. I thought you were asking about 2 people who split up shortly before they were due to marry.

Comment: This question was migrated to http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/8826/ways-to-refers-to-two-people-who-were-about-to-marry-or-just-married and has been according locked here